# Stuck on SQL database normalisation

Tags: sql, database-schema

I'm creating a database of motorcycle and was wondering what the best way to go about setting it out is.

i would like to normalise the data as best as possible so save any headaches further down the line.

I anticipate having the following tables so far:

**Manufacturer**
ID,name,country,image

**Model**
ID,name,manufactureID,engine_size,power,torque,description,weight + various other specifications

I'll also want to separate models by type,so should I have a another table with the details below or should I just include this in the model table?

**Type**
ID,Sports,Supersports,Touring,Cruiser,Off-road

Similar to the type, I want to categorise motorcycle by licence type. Again should I create a separate licence table or just have it as a string in the model table.

I'll need front end users to be able to search the database based on type, licence, manufacture and model.

I'll need them to be able to sort by things like weight, power etc..

Is there a best practice approach to this?

Comment: Depends on the relationship between `Model` and `Type`. If `Type` is just a lookup table which contains values defining the type of each model, then you can keep it and add a column `TypeID` in your `Model tbl`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, you should create another table for `TYPE` and add a reference in `Model` table.
2. Yes, you should add licence type also.
3. To sort them by weight,power; you can do it just from your model table.

Comment: Thanks. I'll give that a go. I'm very new when it comes to databases, but this will be an interesting project for me.